# How to create usercontrols dynamically within view in Catel

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, catel

I'm trying to set a part of a View dynamically based on a value selected.
I've already managed to set the View and ViewModel with xaml like this:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
        <v:MyUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>
...

<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyViewModel}" />
```

But this doesn't seem very flexible as I have to add new types to the View every time I get new values to the list.

I think something more dynamic should be possible with Catel (3.9). Like the one in this question: [How Instantiate Control Programmatically in Catel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926169/how-instantiate-control-programmatically-in-catel)

I already tried binding to the ViewModel but Catel doesn't seem to recognize the UserControls and doesn't instantiate the View. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `ViewModelToViewConverter` which does all of this automatically for you.

Comment: Well, almost perfectly: when I set the bound value to null, the last active View stays visible. Initially when the view is null the View is empty. Is there a way to set the View to null so that nothing is visible?

Comment: You can copy / derive the converter and change the behavior. In the end it's all open source ;-)